# bibtex: warnings empty note and address without publisher: justified?

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I have the following bibtex entry:

```
@TechReport{CAlt2,
  author =   {G. Ziegenhals},
  title =    {{U}ntersuchungen zur {W}irkung eines {A}lternativgriffes c2 bei {O}boen},
  institution =  {IfM - Institut für Musikinstrumentenbau e.V.},
  year =     {2015},
  number =   {IfM M 285/2015 - Fassung 2},
  address =      {IfM - Institut für Musikinstrumentenbau e.V. 
Klingenthaler Stra\ss{}e 42 08267 Klingenthal},
  month =    {6}
}

Bibtex complains: 
Warning--empty note in CAlt2
Warning--there's an address but no publisher in CAlt2
```

Ok but note is optional for techreport 
and I do have a publisher... or isn't `publisher=institution??`

Comment: Normally, the publisher is the company or the printing house, being responsible for distribution. The institution might be a science department, an organization etc. In general, those are not equal, in my point of view

Comment: Bibtex does not treat them as equal as far as I know. And `address` is the address of the `publisher` so it makes no sense to have the first without the second. Don't know why it would complain about an empty `note`, though. It could be the style you are using - it might not be optional for that style, even if it is generally optional with the standard styles. But without a minimal working document we can compile which shows what you are doing, this is only a guess. (And seems somewhat unlikely to me.)

Comment: I tried running BibTeX on a `.bib` file with your given entry and it produces no errors. I think without more details (for instance, which bibliography style you are using) it's not possible to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been very long since the question was asked, but I faced the same problem, I solved it by doing the following:

- `address` means the location where the conference took place.
- `publisher` is such as ACM, IEEE, etc.

Let me share with you this example from ACM template, that explains the different fields.

```
@inproceedings{Hagerup1993,
title        = {Maintaining Discrete Probability Distributions Optimally},
author       = {Hagerup, Torben and Mehlhorn, Kurt and Munro, J. Ian},
booktitle    = {Proceedings of the 20th International Colloquium on Automata, Languages and Programming},
series       = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
volume       = {700},
pages        = {253--264},
year         = {1993},
publisher    = {Springer-Verlag},
address      = {Berlin},
}
```

Comment: The question in the OP is about the `techreport` entry, but you are discussing the `inproceedings` entry in your answer. It is not clear to me that your answer solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist the problem has nothing to do with "techreport" the main issue is that the latex was flagging the bib entry with the error that one of the entries are missing. That was the exact issue I faced and that is why I ended up in this question and thought of sharing my answer when I resolved it.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I still don't see what you have done that specifically solves the issue.